# Submit redirect to current url with different "GET" variables

Tags: php, html, forms, get, form-submit

I'm a have a form in a file called `SignUpForm.php`, when it's submitted, the page is redirected to the url `http://localhost/MySite/Includes/SignUp.php?step=1`, and in the file `SignUp.php`
I have a 3 forms, each form is displayed only with its corresponding `?step=x` value. In the first form (the one displayed with `?step=1`) i have the following code

```php
if(isset($_GET['step']) === true && empty($_GET['step']) === false){
        if(isset($_POST['SignUpStep1Submit'])) {
                // some code here
                header('Location: SignUp.php?step=2');
        }

// forms displaying codes with the $_GET['step'] conditions
```

So the issue is I want to submit the first form so it redirects me to the same `.php` file but with ?step=2 after executing the preceding code, and when I submit the form I end up with `http://localhost/MySite/Includes/SignUp.php`... the step variable is not set, and the code in `//some code here` doesn't get executed at all, all it does is redirect me to `SignUp.php` with no `?step` value, leaving me with a blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just change the form action to include the step variable so for form 1 the action would be

```
<form name="form1" action="/signup.php?step=2" method="post"></form>
```

for form 2 it would be

```
<form name="form2" action="/signup.php?step=3" method="post"></form>
```

To check the form values are valid prior to submitting the form, you can use the `pattern` and `required` attributes e.g.

```
<input name="firstname" pattern=".{3,}" required title="Your first name should be at least 3 characters long">

<input name="city" pattern=".{1,30}" required title="The country field shouldn't be more than 30 characters">
```

`required` checks that the input boxes have been filled in.

`pattern` uses regex patterns to check the type of value that has been filled in against...a pattern. There is more information here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: oh my god, I know this, yet it didn't come to my mind at all hahaha, thank you, I feel stupid now x)

Comment: i just realized, sometimes the code does some trimming for the information submitted in the form and if an input is less than a specific number of chars, an error should appear... if i change the form action to include the step variable, the page is always redirected regardless of wether the code of the first form is valid or not, how do i prevent the redirection when the the code is not valid